# IntelliJ 14 + Lombok plugin + @Builder = error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

i have problem with my IntelliJ 14 and Lombok annotation "@Builder".
I've got some class :

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class TransactionFilter {
      private String name;
      private ProductType product;
      ...

      public static TransactionFilterBuilder defaultBuilder() {
         TransactionFilterBuilder builder = builder();
         builder.product(ProductType.DEFAULT);
         return builder;
      }
}
```

And i'm trying to use its's generated builder in another class :

```
import org.---.TransactionFilter.TransactionFilterBuilder;

public class Foo {
   public void boo() {
      TransactionFilterBuilder filterBuilder;
      ...
   }
}
```

#### In both classes i've got some errors

While compiling with Java 1.6 i've got error :

```
TransactionFilter java:26: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TransactionFilterBuilder
location: class org.---.TransactionFilterBuilder
```

Also my tooltip says that in line 26 i've got incompatible types :
    Required : org.---.TransactionFilter.TransactionFilterBuilder
    Found : org.---.TransactionFilter.TransactionFilterBuilder
**This second error is plugin defect i guess and is not important.**

#### Environment :

- 0.9.1 - Lombok plugin version
- 14.0.3 Community - IntelliJ IDEA version
- Java 1.6.0_31 or Java 1.6.0_45 (**Java 1.6 is needed in project**)
- lombock.jar is included in classpath
- Compiler -> Annotation Processors is set for "Enable annotation processing"

In other cases my lombok plugin works fine. Also under Eclipse this example compiles as well. 
But when i'm using IDEA "@Builder" fails.
I'm the only one who uses IntelliJ in my team and I don't want to go back to Eclipse :(.
Anyone had this problem ?
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick update to that issue, some time ago i've repoerted issue to plugin's official GitHub.
https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/91
**Issue with @Builder for Jdk 1.6 is known and won't be fixed.**

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce with a bit different setup:

- Java 8
- Lombok version 1.16.2
- Lombok Plugin 0.9.1
- Gradle 2.3

My code is working fine. Only issue I encountered was following IntelliJ error:

[image: code]

I suppose it may be some plugin issue, because compilation goes without any problem. It may be helpful, I used gradle build task for compilation.

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class Foo {
    private String foo;

    public static FooBuilder fooBuilder(String foo) {
        FooBuilder builder = builder();
        builder.foo(foo);
        return builder;
    }

}

public class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = Foo.fooBuilder("foo").build();
        System.out.println(foo.getFoo());
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    provided
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.2'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lusiak for answer, but it is still not working.

I thought that this two errors are related, but they are not. 
When i'm running this example with Java 1.7 it compiles and only IntelliJ error appears. 

But when i'm compiling with Java 1.6 (which is need in our team project) it fails [link](http://s23.postimg.org/d9f30vs6z/bad.png).

The strangest thing about this is that Eclipse has no problems with compiling this code on Java 1.6...

Comment: Do you use any build system like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Yes, i use Maven. If you want to look at it i've just pushed example on GitHub : https://github.com/Hejwo/LombokPluginApp

Comment: I just clone your repo and it's working fine for me. I don't have Java 6 installed but I changed project language level to 1.6 and set it also in pom.xml and it's still working for me.

Comment: Well, on pure java 1.6 it's not working. Yes, Maven will build the project, but i really need IDEA's auto make feature for hot swaps.

Comment: I've just downloaded jdk1.6.0_45. I run program via IntelliJ Run command. I had to just replace in Edit Configuration IntelliJ Make with Maven compile. I'm not sure if this will be satisfying for you.

Comment: Wow, thanks for commitment ! :-) Unfortunately it's not... I need to make project by tool used in Build->Make project (Ctrl + F9 def keymap). Why so? In modern projects and this example also it would help. But our teams project is little bit old. It's not even an Mvn project at all. We use Tomcat with configured virtualClasspath="C:/example/classes". When I use "make" or "make project automatically" feature it compiles classes to "C:/example/classes" and thanks to Tomcat hot-swap I can see changes instantly without re-deploying. only make-based solutions can help... Damn that's a tough one...

Comment: No problem. There is one more option (rather stupid but working): delombok project before make.

Comment: Have the same issues with Java 8, did you found some solution?